# PHP function loop to check DB for existing string

Tags: php, mysql, function, loops

I am trying to make a PHP function check against a MySQL DB if a value that has been randomly created previously exists, if it does then for it to repeat until it makes a value in which does not exist.

Currently i have failed miserably, although in precedence i believed my method would have worked, it just does not.

**The PHP**

I tried this in the script on its own and then realised that php functions do not run unless they are called.

```
 conn(); //db connection 
    function genID() {
        $newIDref = uuaig(10);
        $queryCHECK = "SELECT *
                        FROM contentArticle_vids
                         WHERE videoArticle_id = '$newIDref'
                    ";
            $resultCHECK = mysql_query($queryCHECK);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($resultCHECK);

        if ($numrows !== 0) {
            genID();
            die();
        }
    }
```

So.. i then tried this, of which then made it really unhappy (broke the whole page).

```
conn(); //db connection 
genID();

function genID() {
    $newIDref = uuaig(10);
    $queryCHECK = "SELECT *
                    FROM contentArticle_vids
                     WHERE videoArticle_id = '$newIDref'
                ";
        $resultCHECK = mysql_query($queryCHECK);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($resultCHECK);

    if ($numrows !== 0) {
        genID();
        die();
    }
        if ($numrows === 0) {
        return $newIDref;
        die();
    }
}
```

For reference the random string generator is the `uuaig(10)`.

I ultimately need the random string generated and then returned if the string is confirmed as non existent in the database.

How do i proceed?

Comment: Where are you actually connecting to your database?

Comment: above this in a function of which is confirmed working. @MichaelO'Brien

Comment: why is `die()` there? for debugging or is the actual code? if you want to recursively call your function, you must end it with `return genID();` please notice that your code is missing `return`, after that, both `die()` are unnecesary

Comment: letme know what is uuaig(), is your custom random string function?

Comment: `uuaig()` is te random string gen yes.

Comment: all that you need is to add `return` before genID(); Is not the best algoritm, as is not necesary to use recursion, also is better to keep this function on the RDBMS, but that corrects your code. I deleted my other comnent about ifs, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Why make a select at all?  Simply put a unique index on videoArticle_id.  Then when you try to generate and insert a new id, just handle the insert failure and retry with a new id.

If you have a code scheme for generating the id's and expect few id collisions, this will be way more efficient.

So your function might look like:

```
function genID() {
    $idSuccess = false;
    $max_retries = 3;
    $i = 1;
    while (false === $idSuccess && $i <= $max_retries) {
        $newIDref = uuaig(10);
        $queryCHECK = "INSERT INTO contentArticle_vids (`videoArticle_id`)
            VALUES ('$newIDref')";
        $idSuccess = mysql_query($queryCHECK);
        $i++;
    }
    if(false === $idSuccess) {
        error_log('Could not generate ID in genID()');
        return false;
    }
    return $newIDref;
}
```

Note I have added a max retry limit so you don't have infinite loop possibility.  Also, note that this will go ahead and reserve the spot for this new unique ID in the DB table.

Finally, it is basically obligatory that I note your are using the deprecated `mysql` extension.  You really should not be writing new code using this extension.

Comment: that is what im trying to achieve, but i wish to cycle in a loop for the id creation and check. I know the chances of it being the same id is slim but i still wish to make it varify the string is ok

Comment: @MikeBrant Might I suggest a `do {...} while()` instead? Would be a bit cleaner and better to read (imo). Also, of [yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions) I am a fan not, but that is totally up to you

Comment: I managed to accomplish my desired result. Ill admin i do like your answer, but it just did not accomplish what was necessary in this case scenario. As for `mysql` query yes i know, i am changing to mysqli on this project.

Comment: @kingzero Yeah do..while is just as valid here and would at least save you from declaring `$idSuccess` before the loop. I am a big fan of yoda conditions as if you make a stupid typo like `(false = $var)` you get a fatal error` whereas `($var = false)` gives you a not always as easy to spot debugging problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering i managed to figure out the correct way to achieve my desired result.

```
//genID();


function genID($newIDref) {
    $status = false;
    $i=0;
    while ($status === false) {
        $newIDref = uuaig(10);
        $queryCHECK = "SELECT *
                        FROM contentArticle_vids
                         WHERE videoArticle_id = '$newIDref'
                    ";
            $resultCHECK = mysql_query($queryCHECK);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($resultCHECK);

        if ($numrows === 0) {
            $status = true;
            return $newIDref;
        }

        $i++;

        // testing
        /*
            if ($i > 5) {
                echo 'fin';
                die();
            }
        */  
        // testing
    }
}

$newIDref = genID($newIDref);
```